# How to style .arb files in android studio

Tags: colors, code-formatting, arb

I'm starting to work with .arb files in Android Studio and I find them quite difficult to read as only plain text.

Is there any way to color or format the structures more readeable?

no style code for .arb

[image: 1]

I tried to find some information, seems that in visual code json settings work the same with .arb, but not in android studio.

example code

[image: 2]

What I expect is, for example, add color to the "@_AUTH":{},

Is that even possible in android studio?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, `.arb` files have the same format as `.json` files. You can easily associate `.arb` files with JSON formatter in Android Studio:

1. Open settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>
2. Go to Editor > File Types
3. In `Recognized File Types` search for `JSON`
4. In `File name patterns` add `*.arb`

Now `.arb` files will be formatted just like JSON files.

Comment: Thanks! 
I cannot add new values, but at least I added some color.
@Kokila check if this work for you